# Soft keybord is over EditText

Tags: android, layout

I have androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView with MaterialCardView and RecyclerViewBelow.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pool_activity_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.activity.TicketActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/comments_list_row"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

In RecyclerView I have some EditTexts. On focus Soft keybord is on and EditText are sometimes under so edited text is not visible.

I tried to add
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
and
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
to manifest but it didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody has similar problem:
https://gist.github.com/grennis/2e3cd5f7a9238c59861015ce0a7c5584 - that is a solution which I used and it works perfectly